# Posting data to external URL from Firefox extension blocked due to Content Security Policy

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, content-security-policy

In a firefox extension I've created, I have jquery that makes an external call to https://mywebsite.com/save.php and sends data there.

Basically:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://mywebsite.com/save.php",
    data: {data: mydata}
});
```

However, I receive an error in the console:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://mywebsite.com/save.php (“connect-src”).
```

I've tried updating my manifest.json to include:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://mywebsite.com/; object-src 'self' https://mywebsite.com/; connect-src 'self' https://mywebsite.com/"
```

but I've had no luck. Does anyone know how I can get this to work? It works in my Chrome extension just fine.

Comment: I don't really understand why `$.ajax` would load a resource in the first place. You're basically doing a request and await for a response, so if this works with Chrome then your server is properly configured, I guess. What does the content of your manifest look like? Did you try using a different method for your request, such as `fetch`, to check if the result is the same? I just tried to POST content to jsonplaceholder.com with `$.ajax` from a popup in a webextension in FF62 and it works for me. There must be something else.

Comment: Are you doing it within the same domain or a different one? Within the same domain is apparently fine.

Comment: I wonder if the site I'm trying to 'control' has a CSP that has to be overriden somehow.

Comment: Yep that's what I'm thinking but honestly my knowledge of CSP is too limited to be sure about this. And it seems strange that it would work with a Chrome addon and not with a Firefox addon, there must be something on the browser side. Maybe check the default Chrome CSP setting and set your Firefox addon the same way.